# ComboBox с элементом "Не выбрано"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Мне нужен `ComboBox` с постоянным элементом "Не выбрано", который означает, что `SelectedValue` равно `null`.

При этом источники данных могут быть различных типов. Будь то `List<MyClass>` или `List<int>`.

Пока что ничего более или менее разумного в голову не приходит. Из неразумного - создать новые коллекции из существующих с первым значением null и использовать их, но что то мне подсказывает, что это лажа.

Comment: А какое вы хотите чтобы было значение когда вы выбираете это "Не выбрано"?

Comment: зы. null в List<> не добавить, вроде...

Comment: @Андрей мне и не нужно добавлять в лист null. Тут главное ,чтобы тип свойства, к которому я буду биндить `SelectedValue` принимал `null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1) Создаем в ресурсах коллекцию, которая привязана к вашим реальным данным:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyKey" Source="{Binding Path=MyData}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

2) Далее у `ComboBox` в качестве `ItemsSource` используем `CompositeCollection`, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
       <CompositeCollection>
           <ComboBoxItem Content="Не выбрано" />
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" />
       </CompositeCollection>
   </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: что в вашем случае окажется в `SelectedValue`?

Comment: А можно это как то универсализировать? А то для каждого ComboBox приходится создавать такую вот коллекцию.

Comment: @Андрей там окажется null

Comment: @iRumba, можно посмотреть в сторону `Attached Property`, `Behavior` или своего контрола, в который вынести код, реализующий данный функционал.