# Как в XAML к ItemsSource добавить саму коллекцию из VM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В VM есть список, нужно его элементы вывести в табах TabControl и еще сделать итоговый таб с контролом, которому нужен весь список. Контролы берутся из ContentTemplateSelector.

Если просто добавить TabItem:

```
<TabControl.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <TabItem Header = "First Tab">
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <AllListControl List="{Binding AllList}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
        <Collection = "{Binding AllList"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</TabControl.ItemsSource>
```

То все работает, но ругается на "System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='TabItem'"

В идеале нужно к CompositeCollection добавить одиночный элемент AllList, но не пойму, как это сделать.

Comment: Формирование коллекции TabItem производится в коде:
[1я ссылка в гугле](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650812/how-do-i-bind-a-tabcontrol-to-a-collection-of-viewmodels?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633061/218063

Comment: В общем, через конвертер сделал, который добавляет к коллекции ее саму и возвращает как List<object>. Во всяком случае VM менять не пришлось.